# restoring SQL Server from backup into a database with different database name?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have been provided SQL Server backups to restore but they have to be restored into new databases with different names on same server.

To explain it, say I have database "MyDB" and its backup "MyDB_full.bac" has been provided. I want to restore it into "MyDB_new".

What I have tried ?

I have tried to restore  it in SSMS but was unsuccessful, since I m getting error message :

> the backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing

Kindly note I don't want to lose basic database "MyDB".

Comment: Does a database with the name "MyDB_new' already exist? Do you want to overwrite it? If so, add the "REPLACE" option to the `RESTORE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/27/sql-server-fix-error-3154-the-backup-set-holds-a-backup-of-a-database-other-than-the-existing-database/) to be particularly helpful. I'll summarize below:
you are probably trying to restore the database on another existing active database. You can run the following query (albeit with your details filled in) to restore your database:

---

RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks
FROM DISK = 'C:\BackupAdventureworks.bak'
WITH REPLACE